# how to build centos 8 singularity container from recipe

Tags: centos8, singularity-container

tried:

```
BootStrap: yum
MirrorURL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-8/8.3.2011/centosplus/x86_64/os/
Include: yum

singularity build --sandbox centos8 centos8.def
INFO:    Starting build...
INFO:    Skipping GPG Key Import
Error: Nothing to do
FATAL:   While performing build: conveyor failed to get: while bootstrapping: exit status 1
```

no idea what the problem is

Thanks!

Comment: Please run with `singularity --verbose build ...` and add the output to your question

Comment: Thank you for the tip!
But --verbose option did not give any more info than without it.
But I found a solution:
use a different URL:
the following URL works:
`
Bootstrap: yum
OSVersion: 8
# MirrorURL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-8/8.3.2011/centosplus/x86_64/os/
MirrorURL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-8/8.3.2011/BaseOS/x86_64/kickstart/
Include: yum

singularity build --sandbox centos8 centos8.def
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use yum as the bootstrap, you can easily build it from docker

```sh
sudo singularity build --sandbox centos8.sif docker://centos:8.3.2011
```

You do not need docker installed to use it as a bootstrap method, it just tells singularity to pull the blobs from docker hub rather than building them itself.